# Printing a document from VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, printing, document

I have an app which monitors a network location for new documents.
They can be word documents, PDF files, spreadsheets etc.

When a document is detected, it is copied to a local folder within c:\Temp.

What I need is for the document, once copied, to be sent to a specified (not default) printer.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to create a variety of functions to print your document. Like using `LPR` to print PDF or PostScript, `Microsoft.Office.Interop` for Word and Excel documents, and so on...  
If it were me, I would use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename)` to determine the file type and then call whichever function was most appropriate...or log that the file was not printable if the format was not handled.

---

**`Microsoft.Office.Interop`**  
Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, you can call the `PrintOutEx` method on a `Workbook` or `Worksheet` and specify which printer to use.  
See:  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.printoutex.aspx  
and  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.printoutex.aspx

With `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` you can set the `ActivePrinter` property of the `Application` and then use the `PrintOut` method on the `Document`.  
See:  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.activeprinter.aspx  
and  
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.printout.aspx

---

**LPR**  
I wrote a tool once that prints PDF and PostScript files. The code was something like:

```
    'Set the IP address of the printer to use.
    If printer1 Then
        printserver = printer1Address
    ElseIf printer2 Then
        printserver = printer2Address
    ElseIf printer3 Then
        printserver = printer3Address
    End If

    'Use LPR to print the file.
    Dim lprProcess As New Process()
    With lprProcess.StartInfo
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .FileName = "CMD"
        .Arguments = "/c LPR -s " & printserver & " -P P3 " & myNewFileName
    End With
    lprProcess.Start()
```

LPR is not a included by default in Windows 7 and above, but it is a cake-walk to turn on. See steps 1-3 on http://campus.mst.edu/cis/desktop/documentation/pc/win7_x64/lpr_printer/install.htm